# birt grouping - duplicate name

Tags: birt

I dont know whats the problem.
Works on eclipse 
But not when i run it on the server (BirtViewer)

org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Duplicate column name: Name.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1245)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1224)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:96)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this exception select the table column and in the general properties click the Suppress duplicates checkbox.For more details view [this](http://birtworld.blogspot.in/2010/10/birt-duplicate-rows.html) tutorial of avoiding duplicate columns.

Cheers